# swapping dimensions of array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, dimensions

I'm just wondering if there is a way of swapping indexes of a matrix using C++ which corresponds to the numpy function: numpy.swapaxes
For example I have a four dimension array [4,4,2,1] and I want to obtain a new array [4,1,2,4].

Comment: There's no standard matrix type in C++. If you're talking about a multidimensional array, then you can have an intermediate function or class do the index changes for you.

Comment: There is no such thing as a matrix in C++, so how are you representing such a thing?   Without that morsel of information, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: As far as I know.... the slow way. Loops and sets.... If I'm wrong, then god help me I've been doing it wrong for years.